# Perl foreach loop dilema

Tags: xml, perl, loops, foreach

I am looping through XML nodes and creating a group for each alike node, for instance the following nodes:

```
<node name="ps1_uat1" host="" port="20014" />
<node name="ps1_uat2" host="" port="20014" />
<node name="ps1_uat3" host="" port="20014" />
```

...would generate the following group:

```
<nodeGroup name="ps1" nodes="" />
```

All is good there, however when looping through with the code below, I'm getting lost in my loops and it prints out:

```
<nodeGroup name="ps1" nodes="ps1_it," />
<nodeGroup name="ps1" nodes="ps1_it, ps1_uat1," />
<nodeGroup name="ps1" nodes="ps1_it, ps1_uat1, ps1_uat2," />
<nodeGroup name="ps1" nodes="ps1_it, ps1_uat1, ps1_uat2, ps1_uat3," />
```

I only want it to print out the last one, I'm trying to gather all of the alike nodes, and push them into the `@nodes` array, then print it in the nodes attribute.

My Perl Code:

```
foreach my $group (@groups) {
    my @nodes;
    foreach my $node (@nodenames) {
        chomp($group);
        chomp($node);
        if ($node =~ m/$group/) {
            push (@nodes, "$node,");
            my $groupxml = "\t<nodeGroup name=\"$group\" nodes=\"@nodes\" \/>\n";
            print ODSERVERFILE $groupxml;
        }
    }
}
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to move two lines of code out of the inner for loop. Try this:

```
foreach my $group (@groups) {
my @nodes;
 foreach my $node (@nodenames) {

    chomp($group);
    chomp($node);

    if ($node =~ m/$group/) {
       push (@nodes, "$node,");
    }
 }
 // These 2 lines go out
 my $groupxml = "\t<nodeGroup name=\"$group\" nodes=\"@nodes\" \/>\n";
 print ODSERVERFILE $groupxml;
 }
}
```

Comment: That did it. So simple, yet missed. Thank you very much.